# Can I have 2 folders from 2 different servers in sync one way

Tags: windows, bash, ftp, automation, sync

Can I have 2 folder from 2 different server in sync one way!

- I have a Windows server, Server 1 :public server
- a Windows server, Server 2: local on my network :under NAT

The problem is that I get some files in a folder on Server 1 and I have to copy them to a local network drive (Server 2 local network), and delete the original (space limit).

The way I am doing this now is that I have Filezila open in Server 2 and refresh to see for new files. If yes I download them and delete the original. ( I have map the network driver as local under the " Z:" driver letter).

I need a way to do this automatic. I have tried Bit Torrent Sync but I delete the backup if I delete original or the other way. And make duplicate file.

I need a sync like Dropbox but after download from Server 1 I can delete the original or move the back up without sync them again.

NOTE: I will be very happy if it can be done secure like sftp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a client program on SERVER 2 that monitors the mapped drive for new files. New files can be detected by the program based on filename and timestamp. The most important thing that program needs to take care of is whether the file is still being written to disk on the monitored directory or you risk transferring corrupt data.

The program can be written in any programming language of your choice, I would recommend either Java or .NET (C#, VB.NET).

If you are looking for commercial software please look into using JSCAPE's [JSCAPE MFT Server](http://www.jscape.com/products/file-transfer-servers/jscape-mft-server/) which implements [directory monitors](http://files.jscape.com/secureftpserver/docs/index.html?overview10.htm) & is designed to do exactly this.